# How to install Plymouth (splash screens)

Tags: software-installation, themes, plymouth

I have installed plymouth using the command

```
sudo apt install plymouth-x11
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
There are 2 choices for the alternative default.plymouth (providing /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth).

  Selection    Path                                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth                 110       auto mode
  1            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth                 110       manual mode
  2            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth   100       manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 
appu@appu-try:~$ plymouth-set-default-theme space-sunrise -R
plymouth-set-default-theme: command not found
appu@appu-try:~$ plymouth-set-default-theme
plymouth-set-default-theme: command not found
```

How to install plymouth and get rid of the error messages and make it detect a new theme? I use Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: `plymouth-set-default-theme` is a Debian command and not an Ubuntu command.  The command of `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` is how you set the Plymouth themes.  There are lots of themes to install, but none that I can see that are `space-sunrise` in their names.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have found space-sunrise in https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1000039/ Anyway, I was trying to create my own. I thought all Debian commands work in Ubuntu. I shall edit the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command of `plymouth-set-default-theme` is a Debian command and not used in Ubuntu.  Ubuntu uses `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` to set the default Plymouth theme.

Any Plymouth theme that you use needs to be installed into one of two directories.  You can install them in `/lib/plymouth/themes` or `/usr/share/plymouth/themes`.

After you have the Plymouth theme installed into the directory, you will need to add the theme to the `default.plymouth`.  To add the theme you add it like so:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/space-sunrise/space-sunrise.plymouth 100
```

Then you run the `--config` option so that you can choose the new Plymouth theme:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

Now you should see the new theme and you can choose it:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
There are 4 choices for the alternative default.plymouth (providing /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth).

  Selection    Path                                                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/xubuntu-logo/xubuntu-logo.plymouth     150       auto mode
* 1            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/Chicago95/Chicago95.plymouth           80        manual mode
  2            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/RetroTux/RetroTux.plymouth             70        manual mode
  3            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/space-sunrise/space-sunrise.plymouth   100       manual mode
  4            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/xubuntu-logo/xubuntu-logo.plymouth     150       manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3
```

After you have it chosen, you should now update your initramfs:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

And since you have installed the `plymouth-x11` package, you can test out the new Plymouth with the following command that will show it to you for 10 seconds.  (It may not show any animations depending on the Plymouth theme).

```
sudo plymouthd ; sudo plymouth --show-splash ; sleep 10 ; sudo killall plymouthd
```

Reboot the system to see the new changes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Upvoted and selected.