# Can't get nice boot loader screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub-efi, surface

I'm following the instructions [here](https://github.com/timobaehr/Surface-Boot-Themes/blob/surface_book/README.md), with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and have / have executed the following in /etc/grub.d:

Steps 1 - 3: Ok

Step 4: **linux_10**:

```
Open /etc/grub.d/10_linux and search for (towards bottom):    
echo "submenu '$(gettext_printf "Advanced options for %s" "${OS}" | grub_quote)'
Insert the following immediatly after:    
--class recovery --class repair
```

Result:

```
echo "submenu '$(gettext_printf "Advanced options for %s" "${OS}" | grub_quote)' \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-$boot_device_id' {"
--class recover --class repair
```

Step 5: **30_uefi-firmware**

```
Open /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware and search for (towards the bottom) :
menuentry '$LABEL'
Insert the following immediatly after:
--class secure --class recovery
(note: replace LABEL=System Setup with LABEL=Secure Boot)
```

*I can not execute "(note: replace `LABEL=System Setup with LABEL=Secure Boot`)", as there is no `LABEL=System Setup` line; only `LABEL="UEFI Firmware Settings"`.*

```
menuentry '$LABEL' \$menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
        fwsetup
}
--class secure --class recovery
```

Step 6: *25_custom* / **30_os-prober:

*I have not run `boot-repair`, so the first part is irrelevant. For the second part:*

```
If not, open /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober and search for :
'$(echo "${LONGNAME} $onstr" | grub_quote)' --class windows
Replace ${LONGNAME} $onstr with Windows (note: edit title as desired.)
```

*This is no there is no `'$(echo "${LONGNAME} $onstr" | grub_quote)' --class windows` line, so I can't execute the instructions*

At the end, I ran `sudo update-grub`. Upon reboot, I get the old terminal boot menu.

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to achieve, but it is **always** a bad idea to manipulate the grub directly and not in /etc/default/grub.cfg. Reason: your changes will be overwritten every time grub updates. Last but not least these instructions refers to an outdated grub version...

Comment: Thank you. I have setup my MS Surface Book with a dual-boot with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and trying to get a nicer-looking bootloader as in [here](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/13302336/24071553/372b5088-0bd5-11e7-820c-ae84d3cbd1f9.jpg), using [these](https://github.com/timobaehr/Surface-Boot-Themes/blob/surface_book/README.md) instructions.

Comment: Yes, the instructions are from 2017, that is 5 years ago. A time in which grub has evolved. What happens if you omit the steps 4 onward? (which obviously breaks grub). You have a theme and an instruction to to use it. That's fine. The tweaking of those other files - are they necessary?. BTW: Whenever you call "update-grub" all those changes will be overwritten - that is what I meant with "overwritten"

Comment: I think you're after `plymouth`? This might help, https://askubuntu.com/a/1399868/29073. You maybe want "nosplash quiet" in your grub line too?? Never been interested in that myself so can't help further.

Comment: Thank you @kanehekili - yes I knew the instructions were outdated, but that's all I had to go on. Anyway, your suggestion got me exactly what I wanted. If you repost your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions are from 2017, that is 5 years ago. A time in which grub has evolved.

Since step 4 onward obviously breaks grub, try to omit them. Setting the theme as described and the instructions in `/etc/default/grub.cfg` to use them should suffice.

The tweaking of the other files may be in vain,since every time you call `sudo update-grub` those files are generated or altered.