Cant reinstall plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
Newbie here, trying to reinstall the default ubuntu boot logo after trying out kubuntu-desktop and then removing it. The bootscreen didnt revert. When I run sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth the options are:
0            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth                     110  
auto mode
  
1            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth                     110       
manual mode
  
2            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth       100       
manual mode

ubuntu-logo just doesnt exist.
This is what i get if I run sudo apt install plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo and if I try to install those packages it just says theyre already installed
~$ sudo apt-get install plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo : Depends: plymouth (= 0.9.3-1ubuntu7) but
24.004.60-1ubuntu7 is to be installed
                          Depends: plymouth-label (= 0.9.3-1ubuntu7) but
24.004.60-1ubuntu7 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Currently I have the theme with the "Ubuntu 24.04" text with 4 dots underneath

This question is similar to: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Providing your release details is actually very important; as your versions match an EOL/EOSS system most correctly, but also others match a supported system, so your release is very much involved in your issue, but you didn't provide that critical detail.

The Following link (answer 1) suggests how to install the default Ubuntu plymouth screen.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399671/how-to-install-plymouth-splash-screens
